# npm does not install the package.json dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I've been struggling with a weird bug. I'm trying to install project dependencies on my server with a simple `npm i` but it does not create any `node_modules` folder.

Also, I've tried all of the probable solutions like `npm init` in order to make a new `package.json` file or I deleted `package-lock.json` file.

However, the `package.json` file works smoothly on my local environment.

here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "expressmvc",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Webpack and Express backend boilerplate Edit",
  "main": "app.babel.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.3",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.16.0",
    "connect-mongo": "^1.3.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "cron": "^1.3.0",
    "debug": "~2.6.0",
    "express": "~4.14.1",
    "express-session": "^1.15.5",
    "gmail-api-sync": "^1.2.8",
    "gmail-sender-oauth": "^1.0.5",
    "googleapis": "^21.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.9.2",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "node-cron": "^1.2.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^1.0.0",
    "pug": "~2.0.0-beta10",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "mocha": "^3.5.0",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.1.0",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha 'app/**/*.test.js' --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node ./build/backend.js",
    "run-dev": "DEBUG=express:* nodemon  ./app.js --exec babel-node",
    "build": "rm -f -r build && NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./webpack.config.js --progress --profile --colors"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/PedramMarandi/express-js-boilerplate.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "expressjs",
    "boilerplate",
    "es6",
    "javascript",
    "MVC"
  ],
  "author": "Pedram Marandi",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/PedramMarandi/express-js-boilerplate/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/PedramMarandi/express-js-boilerplate#readme"
}
```

NPM version **3.10.10**

Node version **6.10.3**

Comment: Maybe a permission problem? Have you checked permission and owner of files? What errors do you get?

Comment: @Black-Hole G'day mate, there's not any error. Even I do have the npm installation progress bar.  I tried to do it by sudo but nothing logical happened.

Comment: @Black-Hole However, when I do ``npm i --save express`` it works. I think the problem could be with my ``package.json`` file. But as I told it's working on my local environment.

Comment: Is this a script triggering, or are you sshed directly into that box?

Comment: @DanCrews That's an SSH

Comment: Use npm i --verbose  try to catch any error or warning. Pipe it to file if necessary. Also test using yarn instead of npm, it my fails too and shows you the same suorce off a silent error. Or maybe you choose to use yarn.

Comment: Guys, thank you guys for your helps. I tried --verbose and I found somewhere through ``npm i`` it's killed. That was a problem with my memory swapping.

Answer (score -1):

This issue is mainly due to permission problem on Linux machine . You can try after changing the write permission of your deployment folder using this command

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/nodejsAppFloder
```

Comment: It didn't work mate. I've tried it before. btw thank you for your answer

Comment: There is not any error mate even npm installation progress bar shows everything is okay.